# FLUENT-mesh conversion to polyhedra creates holes

Tags: mesh, fluent, ansys, polyhedra, tetrahedra

Goodmorning!
I have a straight duct with square cross section and I created a simple tetrahedral mesh with ansys. I imposed the dimension of the cells and an inflation layer at the wall. Then I uploaded it on fluent to perform a simulation and I clicked on "make polyhedra". Then I ran the simulation and I saw that the continuity increased incontrollably. I saw the contours and I noticed that there are small holes in the domain. I think that it could be due to the conversion from tetrahedral to polyhedra. Is it possible? How can I solve this problem?

I have also checked the quality of the tetrahedral mesh, however everything seems to be ok.
Thank you very much for your help.